# DOMContentLoaded inside $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domready

At the moment I try get familiar with a plugin. On the plugin-homepage, there are several examples on how to use it.

In one example there is this code:

```
function loaded() {
        iScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    //Use this for high compatibility (iDevice + Android)
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        setTimeout(loaded, 200);
    }, false);
```

As I am also using jQuery, I want to use that code inside `$(document).ready`, which is basically the jQuery way of doing `DOMContentLoaded` I believe.
So is it safe to remove `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {` & `}, false);`, leaving only `setTimeout(loaded, 200);` inside `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, jQuery uses `DOMContentLoaded` event when it's available, if your code lies inside the `ready` callback, you can omit `DOMContentLoaded`.

From the source code:

```
// Standards-based browsers support DOMContentLoaded
} else if ( document.addEventListener ) {
    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false );
```